# unexpected thumbprint when connecting via remote desktop - what now?

Tags: windows, certificate-authority, cloud-computing, remote-desktop

I have an Amazon EC2 instance in a VPC.

I have not logged into it for some time, so I used the Amazon EC2 CLI with `ec2-get-console-output` to check what the thumbprint should be when I connect. To my surprise, the thumbprint on the certificate, in the remote desktop warning screen, was wrong.

I have connected to it via RDP in the past, and I am pretty sure the certificate thumbprint was as expected. I checked other instances and they matched their CLI output.

I am wondering if this could be something to do with the instance being in a VPC? It could also be a man-in-the-middle attack, I guess. The server is sufficiently important to draw unwelcome attention.

Currently I am afraid to log in, so what is the next step? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a reboot being required, after something has happened to cause the OS certificate to change, in order for the new certificate thumbprint to show up in the output of the Amazon CLI `ec2-get-console-output` command.